# How do I check if field value in dictionary and then conditionally assign values?

Tags: dictionary, ms-access, data-structures, vba

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Use VBA to loop through a table, and assign gifts to people using the following three parameters:

1) The individual's priority score.

2) The individual's preferences on what gift to receive.

3) The number of that type of gift available in inventory.

Ideally, the VBA would start from the 1st record of Priority 1 group, assign their most preferred gift if in stock, and then continue assigning Priority 1 individuals according to their preference, while checking the inventory.

After **all** Priority 1 individuals are assigned a gift (given a 'Assigned_Gift') value in the table object 'tbl_Gift_Assignments'), the VBA moves to Priority 2 individuals, and so forth.

Right now, I am having trouble handling instances where a preferred gift item an individual has is not listed in the inventory table.

In my database, I have the following table (table object called 'tbl_Gift_Assignments'):

```
RecordID | Gift_Assignment | Priority |   Name      | Preference_1 | Preference_2 |... Preference_n

   001                          1        John          Sled         Racecar                      
   002                          1        Jane          Racecar      Television
   003                          1        Joe           Mobile       Jacuzzi   
   004                          1        Moe           PS4          Xbox
   005                          2        Sam           Laptop       PS4
   006                          2        Alek          Laptop       PS4
   007                          3        Paul          Jacuzzi      Xbox
   008                          3        Nicky         Racecar      Television
```

Additionally, I have a table that tells me how many of each item we have in stock in our inventory (table object called 'tbl_Inventory'):

```
ItemID | Number_in_stock 

 Laptop         4             
 PS4            4
 Xbox           4
 Television     4
```

In order to accomplish this task, I am using the dictionary object to cache inventory per gift into an in-memory dictionary. It decrements inventory each time I assign a gift to a record.

The VBA I have so far is as follows:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim GiftInvDict As New Scripting.dictionary

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rsInv = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ItemID, Number_in_stock FROM tbl_Inventory")
While Not rsInv.EOF
    GiftsInvDict.Add Cstr(rsInv!ItemID), CInt(rsInv!Number_in_stock)
Loop
rsInv.Close

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Gift_Assignments WHERE Priority =1"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do Until rs.EOF
    With rs
    'Process for each preferred item
    'Path #1_step_a: If preferred item is not in dictionary
        If Not GiftsInvDict.Exists(Cstr(rs!Preference_1)) Then
            ' Path #1_step_b: Add it to dictionary, with value of 0
            GiftsInvDict.Add Cstr(rsInv!Preference_1), 0 Then
            ' Path #1_step_c: Don't know how to tell it to jump
            ' to next preference
        End If
        ' Path #2_step_a: If preferred item is actually in dictionary
        ElseIf GiftInvDict.Exists(Cstr(rs!Preference_1)) Then
            ' Path #2_step_b: Check that the inventory is greater than 0
            If GiftsInvDict(Cstr(rs!Preference_1)) > 0 Then
                ' Path #2_step_c: If inventory greater than 0, change
                ''Gift_Assignment' value to preference
            .Edit
            !Gift_Assignment = rs!Preference_1
            .Update
            GiftsInvDict(!Preference_1) = GiftsInvDict(!Preference_1) - 1
            End If 
        'End of process for each preferred item 

        'Do the process again for 'Preference_2....Preference_N' until all preferences
        'are checked

        'If, after each preference has been through the process, preferred gifts cannot be assigned 
        'assign 'No_Gift_Available' value to 'Gift_Assignment' field
        Else
            .Edit
            !Gift_Assignment = "No_Gift_Available"
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    End With
Loop

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

**Challenges**

I know that individuals have listed preferences that are not in stock (not listed in the 'tbl_Inventory', like 'Jacuzzi', 'Sled', 'Racecar'). My current approach, because I do not know how to have the VBA skip gift preferences that are not in the dictionary object, is to have the VBA check if the preferred item exists in the dictionary object. If it doesn't, add the key to the dictionary with a value of 0. Right now, the VBA is just skipping to the 'Else' condition, where you assign no gift to the individual, even though they have other preferred gifts that are in stock (that may exist in the dictionary object).

Comment: As a general rule, if you have numbered fields / columns (pref_1, pref_2), you need to reconsider your database design.

Comment: If 'Pref_1 is not available, but Pref_2 is, are you supposed to assign that?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made a little progress with your code. Not sure if you were in a hurry with the above, or problems with cut/paste, but there were at least 5 or 6 compile errors that I had to correct.

I just simplified the code you had so that it would check preferences in order.  There are several things you will need to address, depending on what you want to do. Here are my suggestions:

1. Modify your query to select ALL from tbl_GiftAssignments and sort by priority. That way you can handle all in one loop.
2. Not sure how many 'Preference' fields you will have, but if more than three (or if it will change), then I suggest creating a loop inside the 'Do While' that will spin through each column.
3. I added code at the end to update the inventory count, but don't like that approach. I feel it should happen at the same time the gift assignment update takes place. If this crashes, you will have a royal mess.
4. I did NOT add any code to add new items to the table. Wasn't sure if that's what you wanted.
5. Finally, there is a bug somewhere in processing the Dictionary to add a new item. If 'Racecar' was not found, it was added, but the next time someone looked for 'Racecar', it got added again!!
6. Finally (really, finally)... You can remove all of my 'Debug.Print' statements

Here is the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Assign_Gifts()

Dim db              As DAO.Database
Dim rs              As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsINV           As DAO.Recordset                        ' ** Not Defined
Dim strSQL          As String
Dim GiftsInvDict    As New Scripting.Dictionary             ' ** Needed 's' / inconsistent
Dim i               As Integer
Dim iQTY            As Integer
Dim itemArray

    Set GiftsInvDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Set rsINV = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ItemID, Number_in_stock FROM tbl_Inventory")
    Do While Not rsINV.EOF          ' Changed to DO
        GiftsInvDict.add CStr(rsINV!ItemID), CInt(rsINV!Number_in_stock)
        rsINV.MoveNext                      ' Missing MOVENEXT
    Loop                ' ** Loop without Do
    rsINV.Close


    Debug.Print "----- INVENTORY -----"
    Debug.Print "Count: " & GiftsInvDict.Count & vbTab & "C2: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Keys) + 1 & vbTab & "C3: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Items) + 1
    For i = 0 To GiftsInvDict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i), GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print "----- NAMES -----"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Gift_Assignments WHERE Priority =1"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    Do Until rs.EOF
        With rs
            Debug.Print rs!Name & vbTab & rs!Preference_1 & vbTab & rs!Preference_2 & vbTab & rs!Preference_n
            ' Check 1st Pref
            If Not GiftsInvDict.Exists(CStr(rs!Preference_1)) Then              ' Fails to find 'Racecar'!!!!
                Debug.Print "1st Pref not avail: " & rs!Preference_1 & vbTab & " add it "
                GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_1)) = 0
                Debug.Print "----- INVENTORY -----"
                Debug.Print "Count: " & GiftsInvDict.Count & vbTab & "C2: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Keys) + 1 & vbTab & "C3: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Items) + 1
                For i = 0 To GiftsInvDict.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i), GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)
                Next i
                Debug.Print "---------------------"
            Else
                iQTY = CInt(GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_1)))
                If iQTY > 0 Then
                    .Edit
                    !Gift_Assignment = rs!Preference_1
                    .Update
                    GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_1)) = CInt(iQTY - 1)
                    GoTo Satisfied
                End If
            End If

            ' Check 2nd Pref
            If Not GiftsInvDict.Exists(CStr(rs!Preference_2)) Then
                Debug.Print "2nd Pref not avail: " & rs!Preference_2 & vbTab & " add it "
                GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_2)) = 0
                Debug.Print "----- INVENTORY -----"
                Debug.Print "Count: " & GiftsInvDict.Count & vbTab & "C2: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Keys) + 1 & vbTab & "C3: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Items) + 1
                For i = 0 To GiftsInvDict.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i), GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)
                Next i
                Debug.Print "---------------------"

            Else
                iQTY = CInt(GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_2)))
                If iQTY > 0 Then
                    .Edit
                    !Gift_Assignment = rs!Preference_2
                    .Update
                    GiftsInvDict.Item((CStr(rs!Preference_2))) = CInt(iQTY - 1)
                    GoTo Satisfied
                End If
            End If

            ' Try 3rd choice --- being lazy, BUT I WOULD CHANGE ALL THIS CODE TO HANDLE ANY NUMBER OF PREDERENCES!!
            If Not IsNull(rs!Preference_n) Then
                If Not GiftsInvDict.Exists(CStr(rs!Preference_n)) Then
                    Debug.Print "nth Pref not avail: " & rs!Preference_n & vbTab & " add it "
                    GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_n)) = 0
                    Debug.Print "----- INVENTORY -----"
                    Debug.Print "Count: " & GiftsInvDict.Count & vbTab & "C2: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Keys) + 1 & vbTab & "C3: " & UBound(GiftsInvDict.Items) + 1
                    For i = 0 To GiftsInvDict.Count - 1
                        Debug.Print GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i), GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)
                    Next i
                    Debug.Print "---------------------"

                Else
                    iQTY = CInt(GiftsInvDict.Item(CStr(rs!Preference_n)))
                    If iQTY > 0 Then
                        .Edit
                        !Gift_Assignment = rs!Preference_n
                        .Update
                        GiftsInvDict.Item(!Preference_n) = CInt(iQTY - 1)
                        GoTo Satisfied
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Pref_n is NULL"
            End If

            .Edit
            !Gift_Assignment = "No_Gift_Available"
            .Update

            'End of process for each preferred item

            'Do the process again for 'Preference_2....Preference_N' until all preferences
            'are checked

            'If, after each preference has been through the process, preferred gifts cannot be assigned
            'assign 'No_Gift_Available' value to 'Gift_Assignment' field
Satisfied:
            .MoveNext
        End With
    Loop

    rs.Close

    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"

    'Add code to insert new records into Inventory if desired....
    For i = 0 To GiftsInvDict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i), GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)
        strSQL = "UPDATE tbl_Inventory SET tbl_Inventory.Number_in_stock = " & CInt(GiftsInvDict.Items()(i)) & " " & _
                 "WHERE (((tbl_Inventory.ItemID)='" & CStr(GiftsInvDict.Keys()(i)) & "'));"
        db.Execute strSQL, , iRecAff
    Next i

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @Wayne_G_Dunn: The step-by-step explanation of your approach is excellent. I also think that it is best not to update the inventory count. Additionally, as you guessed correctly, I did not want to add items to table.